# How to factor a simple algebraic expression?

Tags: cubics

I am struggling to factor a larger expression. I seem to have forgotten how to do it, hence I am coming here for help, so that I can refresh the concept.

The equation is 
$$x^3+2x+3=0$$

How do solve it by splitting the middle term? I tried the total and error method, and subsequent long division to obtain 
$$(x+1)(x^2-x+3)$$

So I have indeed found the factors, but how to do it without lengthy calculations? The middle term can be split, I have just forgotten how to.

Edit: I see that splitting the middle term is the wrong term. Forgive me.

What I meant was using formulas like $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$

I am fairly confident that’s how it’s done, because I have used this before.

It’s extremely embarrassing to ask this, but it had to be done.

Comment: "*The middle term can be split*" Uhm... are you sure you aren't misremembering techniques learned for the purposes of factoring quadratics which don't apply to factoring cubics?  There *does* exist a general approach for cubics, but people very infrequently learn it beyond having learned about its existence, and fewer still use it in practice.

Comment: The most generalized approach to factoring a cubic that is commonly used is called Cardano's Formula.  [This Mathologer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-KXStupwsc&t=1034s) video is well worth watching from the beginning for anyone even mildly interested in this, but if you just want a quick answer you might just care about watching from where I timestamped.  Reading about it instead at [proof wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_Formula) can also help.

Comment: Most commonly, when encountering a problem like this, Cardano's Formula is *not* what is intended to be used (*though works wonders if you can master it*).  What is instead commonly intended is checking to see if $0,1,-1,2,-2$ or other quickly identifiable numbers are a root, and then perform long division as you had.

Comment: @JMoravitz Better yet, knowing the rational root theorem, only checking the divisors of the constant term $3$.

Comment: @JMoravitz please check the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was at university, we did this kind of factorisation thru the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

> If $\frac pq$ is a rational root of a polynomial (with integer
>   coefficients), then $p$ divide the constant term and $q$ divide the
>   main coefficient.

In your example
$$x^3+2x+3$$
we must have $p|3$ and $q|1$.  We only have to check for $\pm1$ and $\pm3$.

---

You asked if there was a way to split the middle terms (there are two middle terms). We could develop something similar to quadratic factorisation. Let's work backward.
$$(x+1)(x^2-x+3)$$
We distribute the first factor thru the second
$$x^2(x+1)-x(x+1)+3(x+1)\tag{1}$$
distribute again
$$x^3+x^2-x^2-x+3x+3\tag{2}$$
If we want to split the middle terms, we need to find equation $(2)$.

Starting with your polynomial
$$x^3+2x+3$$
We are looking for integers $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ to split the middle term like this
$$x^3+Ax^2+Bx^2+Cx+Dx+3$$
with conditions
$$A+B=0\tag{Cond1}$$
$$C+D=2\tag{Cond2}$$
Futhermore, we want to be able to factorise it to look like equation $(1)$. With the first two terms, there is a $x^2$ in common
$$x^2(x+A)+Bx^2+Cx+Dx+3$$
We want to have the exact same parenthesis with the other four terms, so we need
$$x^2(x+A)+Bx\left(x+\tfrac CB\right)+D\left(x+\tfrac3D\right)$$
For the parenthesis to be the same, we need 
$$A=\frac CB\tag{Cond3}$$
$$A=\frac3D\tag{Cond4}$$
From $(\text{Cond}4)$, $D=\pm1$ or $D=\pm3$. From $(\text{Cond}1)$, $A=-B$, combined with $(\text{Cond}3)$, $C=-A^2$. We now try a value of $D$, which force the other value, finally check if it fits in $(\text{Cond}2)$

The one that work is $D=3$, then $A=1$, $C=-1$ and $B=-1$. It is easy to see $C+D=2$.
$$x^3+Ax^2+Bx^2+Cx+Dx+3$$
$$x^3+x^2-x^2-x+3x+3$$
$$x^2(x+1)-x(x+1)+3(x+1)$$
$$(x+1)(x^2-x+3)$$

It work realatively well since the polynomial is simple. It could be a lot more complicated if the leading coefficient was different of $1$.

Comment: How did you establish the conditions? A+B=0 known only because we knew what the final equation was going to be

Comment: We start with your polynomial $x^3+2x+3$. Since it doesn't have a term in $x^2$, then $Ax^2+Bx^2$ must be $0$. Thus $A+B=0$.